# Python: comparing two iterating tables

Tags: python, mysql

I don't know if asking Python questions here is right or not but here I got.
This thing has me stumped.
I have a python script which connects to a MySQL DB, and takes a table of datetime results, so far so good. Within python it then copies that list under another variable list having added 90 days on top of the original list. So now I have two lists: 1 I pulled straight from the DB, one that's the original + 90 days.
But what I then need to do is to iterate through the original list, and for each original date compare it to every new date. For example.

Say I have the original table with dates like this:
a, b, c, d, e, f, g... after the + 90 days I also have a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1.
Then it has to follow this pattern:
compare a to a1, a to b1, a to c1, a to d1, etc. Then, it moves on to comparinng b to a1, b to b1, b to c1 etc etc.

I thought I'd nest two for loops, but that had an undesired effect.

How would I carry this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly (small samples are always helpful).

I think nested for-loops are the correct way to do it, maybe you did something wrong?
There is also [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which does that for you faster. Here's a small example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> x = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> y = ["d", "e", "f"]
>>> for t in product(x, y):
...   print t
... 
('a', 'd')
('a', 'e')
('a', 'f')
('b', 'd')
('b', 'e')
('b', 'f')
('c', 'd')
('c', 'e')
('c', 'f')
>>>
```

Comment: You are brilliant! That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: No problem @Xtremesupremacy3! Don't forget to mark the answer.